# how-to deploy files to several nodes on network automatically?

Tags: windows, automation, network-share, automated-install

need to push(deploy) few batch files to the machines on a network. All nodes are running Windows.
The batch files contain some commands to initialize an env on each node.

what ways can this be accomplished? any tools readily available? thanks in adv.

Comment: So you want to just copy the files to the computers? What's wrong with a quick batch/PS file to copy them?

Comment: just to copy the files to multiple nodes on network and launch the batch files automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create list of computers in a file (not exactly necessary, but usually the easiest), named `computer.list` (or whatever):

   ```
   wsn101
   wsn102
   wsn103
   ```
2. Run batch file:

   ```
   for %%i in (computer.list) do copy file_to_push.ext \\%%i\c$
   for %%i in (computer.list) do psexec \\%%i C:\file_to_push.ext
   ```

   <sub>(Fixed this part, `cp` isn't right, should be `copy`)</sub>
   [Link to download psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) if you don't have it already.

   Same thing in PS:

   ```
   foreach ($wsn in Get-Content Computer.List)
   {
       cp file_to_push.ext \\$wsn\c$
       psexec \\$wsn C:\file_to_push.ext
   }
   ```

Comment: should these hostnames resolve to IPs?

Comment: @John, yes the names must resolve via NetBIOS or DNS; unless you're using NetBEUI.

Comment: the above code is not working "syntax error in for loop"...I am not good in MS DOS batch...could you help pls? any equivalent in powershell?

Comment: @John - I updated the batch script with the correct %%i syntax.  The %i would only work when typed from a command line.

Comment: @Doug, thank you, been too long since I used batch files apparently.

Comment: FYI I had to put FOR /F into my script otherwise it told me the text file (list file) was "unexpected at this time"